# Android Studio remove appcompact-v7 library

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

Hi in my project Iam using

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```

for support library I don't want to use `appcompat-v7` and `mediarouter` but they are getting generated under `/exploded-aar/com.android.support`.
My project was originally made for `Ant build system` and after I imported it in Android Studio it's been built for `Gradle` and it was working till I updated  SDK (by mistake) and now I can't build project because of conflicts.

I tried to remove it from `app.iml`

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="appcompat-v7-22.2.0" level="project" />
```

But after I clean and rebuild project it's back again

Comment: Have you tried gradle clean?

Comment: yes I tried it but it didn't worked for me